# Direct and reported speech, and how they work

Tags: reported-speech

> She said, "I'll call you when I get off work." - Direct speech
>
> She said she'd call me when she got off work. - Reported speech

Is the above example correct grammatically?

At what points do we choose not to backshift the tenses in reported speech?
Could we do that anytime we want without worry whether it'd be grammatically wrong?
Or should I try to backshift tenses in reported speech always?

Comment: If it's not "direct speech" (with quote marks around the *exact* words as spoken), you can only choose *not* to backshift *(She said **she'll** call me when she **gets** off work)* if you're saying this at some point ***before*** she finishes work. If it's later than that (regardless of whether she did in fact call or not) you must backshift.

Comment: If i choose to backshift knowing she hasn't got off work yet, that'd be okay right? So long as she doesn't get off work, i could backshift the tenses to the past, or i could keep them in the present tense, right?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't express myself well. You can ***always*** choose to backshift, regardless of whether you're speaking before or after the time (in *her* future) that she was referring to. But you can't choose ***not*** to backshift *after* that time (i.e. if she finishes work at 5:00pm, you can't use the non-backshifted *She said she'll call me when she gets off work* at 9:00pm unless there are strong contextual reasons for supposing that on this particular occasion she's working very late, so she *still* hasn't finished).

Comment: Okay. 
Thanks.
I have a few more questions concerning the usage of the second conditional, do you think you could help me out answering my questions for me?

Comment: Sure, if you post them as Questions here on ELL. Note that I haven't posted an actual Answer on this page because (1) I wouldn't be surprised to discover it's a duplicate, and (2) it's possible there are exceptions to the things I've asserted in my comments. I haven't meaningfully *studied* things like this since I was at school many decades ago (and even then, not much). I just speak and write English as a native.

Comment: That's good enough for me. 
I actually don't care much for formal writing.
I'm just pedantic about the ways certain sentences are constructed, and whether they're grammatically correct or not.

Comment: Would you mind helping me out over chat? ._.)
Feel free to decline my offer, if you have a problem with it or something.. :p

Comment: Okay - I'm in [ELL's cabin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is correct.

Backshift is not needed when reporting general truths.

Backshift is optional when the situation is still true. E.g.:

> “I want a new dog.”
>
> They said they wanted a new dog. (1)
>
> They said they want a new dog. (2)

(1) might either mean they want a new dog or it might mean that they don't want a new dog anymore (maybe they've gotten one, or have changed their mind, ...).

(2) means they want a new dog.

In general, use backshift unless the situation is still true, in which case you can choose.